# getting the facebook access token from url in flask

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, oauth, flask, rauth

I am writing an app using flask. I am using the RAuth module for OAuth. The url encoded access token that facebook is returning is formatted like `www.myurl.com/authCallback#access_token=<token>`.

I tried getting the raw string of the url using 'request.url', but that only returns `www.myurl.com/authCallback`

I also tried using a decoration of `@app.route('/authCallback/<access_token>')` which gives me a 404.

Is there a way to do this. Has anyone used these to libraries together before?

Comment: Try getting the raw url used in the request : http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.path. Then parse it to extract the access token, and build a route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not take a look at the [Flask example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook)? [Here's the callback view](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/facebook/facebook.py#L79) that handles parsing the code out of the URL.

I would recommend following that example if you can. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Flask-rauth extension. May be it can give you some ideas ?

https://github.com/joelverhagen/flask-rauth

It has an examples section as well which includes facebook

https://github.com/joelverhagen/flask-rauth/blob/master/example/facebook.py